How to get the 3D pose parameters using STAR (SMPL family?)
How can I get the SMPL 3D pose parameters using the STAR?
I want to find the 3D pose parameters from a given input video in the SMPL skeleton format. In order to get this I thought of using the latest upgrade to SMPL (Though it's almost 4 years old). The reason for using this is mostly because it's said to have only 20% parameters of the original SMPL.
There are instructions on how to load the model in the desired framework and setting up but I don't see any instruction on how I can get the pose parameters given a video.
I feel VIBE is a good project on how to get the 3D pose parameters but it uses the SMPL-X and the new one STAR claims that it uses 80% parameters so most likely it'll be faster than that. But I can't figure out how to make use of STAR with in-the-wild videos

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
